# Abrir galeria android desde un html

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview-android

Buenas a todos.

Estoy intentando abrir la galería de Android desde un `.html` que tengo en la carpeta `assets`. Este `.html` lo abro desde un webView y funciona todo genial excepto un botón que debería abrir el explorador de archivos pero no hace nada sin embargo si ese archivo .html lo abro en un navegador de PC si me abre el explorador de archivos.

No se si me he explicado bien, si no lo he hecho decidlo y lo intento explicar de otra manera >.<'

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
       function(editor) {

        function openGallery() {
            var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
            input.attr("type", "file");
            input.attr("accept", "image/*");
            input.trigger('click'); // opening dialog
            return false;
        }

        editor.addButton('openGallery', {
          icon: 'insertdatetime',
          //image: 'http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/icons/search/fugue/icons/calendar-blue.png',
          tooltip: "Insert image",
          onclick: openGallery
        });
    }
```

Eso lo que hace es añadir un botón a un editor de archivos con la funcionalidad de abrir el explorador de archivos, en PC lo abre pero en Android no me hace nada.

Comment: tienes el .html en assets pero que me dices de las fotos que cargan esta galería? @borjis

Comment: Hola, lo pudiste solucionar???

Comment: @Strelok pues no lo conseguí pero busque otra solución que igual a ti no te sirve, abría la galería desde un botón normal y corriente de android y cogía la URI de la imagen, después creaba una etiqueta imagen con esa URI de la imagen y la insertaba en el webview en la parte que necesitaba que en mi caso era un editor de texto.  Un saludo ^^

Comment: @borijs en mi caso es un registro, que requiere una foto, pero no logro hacerlo y tampoco logro obtener mucha ayuda. Tu crees que lo que has hecho me serviría en mi caso?

Comment: Es un registro pero donde esta el formulario de registro??  es una app que carga en un webview una url o directamente es una web que se carga desde el navegador ? Es que en mi caso era un archivo html guardado en mi app que lo habría en un webview